# Which is more optimised making DISTINCT query in MySQL to get unique results or generate a set?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, performance, data-structures

I am trying to fetch unique aocDetailIds in spring boot should I use distinct keyword(Code Block 1)  or should I create a SET of strings(Code Block 2) , which will be more optimised ?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT a.aocDetailId FROM aocParsedDetail a WHERE a.dateCreated >= ?1 AND a.aocParsingStatus = ?2 ORDER BY a.dateCreated")
List<String> findAocParsedDetailIdsOrderByDateCreated(@NotNull long dateCreated, EventStatus aocParsingStatus);
```

```
@Query(value = "SELECT a.aocDetailId FROM aocParsedDetail a WHERE a.dateCreated >= ?1 AND a.aocParsingStatus = ?2 ORDER BY a.dateCreated")
Set<String> findAocParsedDetailIdsOrderByDateCreated(@NotNull long dateCreated, EventStatus aocParsingStatus);
```

Answer (score 0):

This composite index should help performance significantly:

```
INDEX(aocParsingStatus, dateCreated, aocDetailId)
```

The two queries you present are not equivalent.

```
SELECT DISTINCT d
```

potentially returns a 'short' list of different values of `d`.  It is slower because of having to de-dup.

```
SELECT d
```

return all values, even duplicates.  It is slower because of returning more rows.

Maybe this is what you want?

```
SELECT  a.aocDetailId
    FROM  aocParsedDetail a
    WHERE  a.dateCreated >= ?1
      AND  a.aocParsingStatus = ?2
    LIMIT 1
```

This will always be as fast or faster than either of the other formulations, but it returns only one value for `aocDetailId` that matches the `WHEREs`.  This is especially useful if expect only one distinct value or want simply "any" value.

If you are expecting multiple different values, then simply remove the `ORDER BY` from your first query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.aocDetailId
    FROM  aocParsedDetail a
    WHERE  a.dateCreated >= ?1
      AND  a.aocParsingStatus = ?2
```

`ORDER BY dateCreated` is useless.  You might want `ORDER BY aocDetailId`.

Morale of this discussion:

1. Focus on getting the desired result
2. `ADD INDEX(...)`, if necessary, for performance

(My index suggestion works will for all variants discussed above.)

Comment: ORDER BY dateCreated is required as per the defined logic and I do have an index compound index on *aocParsingStatus, dateCreated*

Comment: Changing that index to the 3-column I suggested would give a slight extra boost by being a "covering" index.

Answer (score -1):

In database queries, the efficiency of using the DISTINCT keyword is often relatively low because it requires sorting and deduplication of the result set. If the data volume is large, this operation may consume more time and resources.

In contrast, using Set to receive query results is more efficient because Set has the feature of automatic deduplication. It can perform deduplication operations directly in memory without the need to sort the entire result set.

So from an efficiency perspective, using Set to receive query results may be more efficient. However, it should be noted that using Set will lose the order of query results. If you need to preserve the order of query results, please use List. If the data volume is small, using Distinct will not have a significant impact on performance.

Overall, if you don't have high requirements for the order of the results and the amount of data is not particularly large, you can try using Set to receive query results for higher efficiency. If there are requirements for the order of the results or if the data volume is large, it is recommended to use a List to receive the results after deduplication.

Comment: Unless you have a million rows, you will be hard-pressed to measure the speed difference between DISTINCT, SET, and LIST.  So, use the KISS principle -- DISTINCT is a single word.

Comment: sounds like good

Comment: this makes sense, but I am more interested in knowing how DISTINCT works behind the hood and how Java Creates a set behind the hood and what benchmarks should I look for.